# Active Directory unable to recognize systems

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2008, dhcp, vmware-workstation

**My Configuration:** I'm using Windows Server 2008 from VMware(8.0.0) & it's working fine,Now I have 5 Windows 7 system.And I have created Active Directory and DNS (i.e. abc.com).

**Issue:**  Whenever I'm trying to add those systems into a Group,AD can't detect those 5 systems(I mean hostname at all).

***To Do(?):***

1. Shall I install DHCP into my server,and then add those client manually,and then it'll show in the Active Directory.
   or
2. I have to create a Network domain which makes the server recognize other 5 systems

Any inputs on this regards making my Active Directory recognize 5 other windows7 client will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, lets start old school here: Are the Network Adapters (NIC) compliant with the IPv# form the server is using?  Secondly, have the computers been added to the domain from the computer or AD?=

Comment: @GoldBishop, 1>how to check NIC complaint with IPv# -do suggest(I'm novish in this part)? 2>Here is my questoin, How the computers been added to the domain from AD(AD's not atall showing any added system when I'm trying to create a group or user with having those system) & 3>Is there any need of DHCP ?.... Any suggetion from yourside...//

Comment: posting answer, to your additional questions.

Comment: Did that fix the problem?  I know it was kinda wordy and lengthy but was shooting from the hip and didnt have my usual checklist in front of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok long form answer, so its not in Comment.

1. This is inresponse to the 2 formats out in the market

   - IPV4 - Oldest current standard for 90% of the NIC's on the market now.  100% of the NIC's will be compliant to this standard
   - IPV6 - Newest (~2yrs old) and has roughly 50% market implementation.
   - Acknowledging the industry transition from the IPV4 to IPV6 will help you in solving some DHCP/Network transmission problems.  I know of the problem, have tasked the more specialized Network/System Admins with performing this problem solving.  I know its a task of inventory control and standardization on the infrastructure.
2. First off do you have a Single-Node AD or a Farm?

   - Farm: Do a broad search from the main trunk of AD for the computer.

     - This will do a full "inventory" search.  In the past, the AD implementor didnt setup a default directory for "new" computers and so they went to the top trunk for proper routing.  So i would have to do a top-trunk search for the computer, and once found manually drag it to the correct branch or limb.
   - Single-Node: Follow the same methodology, as above "Farm", but you have less of a headache as your Trunk is more local and not necessarily spread out amongst several locations.
3. There is always a need for DHCP.  Especially if you want to fight against static IP assignment and want to force users to use the Computer Name vs just an IP.  Most Servers use Static DHCP for back-door access for administration.  In my past Computer management, i have used DHCP to implement and enforce a dynamic IP address for the computer to **mitigate** anyone from using an IP address as a entry point into your network.

One way to be 100% sure that the computer is not registered in any way with AD:

1. Login as **Local Administrator** for all these steps, until otherwise stated.
2. Disconnect the computer from the network
3. Change it from Domain to Workgroup (i always use "TEMP" as my Workgroup)
4. Then do the mandatory reboot.
5. Rename the computer to another valid infrastructure naming convention
6. Do mandatory reboot.
7. During this Reboot, reconnect the Patch Cord back to the NIC (preferably before the Black Windows Loading screen)
8. **Optional** Add the new computer name to the needed branch/folder
9. Login as **Local Admin**, change from Workgroup to Domain, authenticate with the AD Administrator's credentials

   - If you error out here, you need to validate that the computer is actually on the network (should have pulled a valid subnet IP address)
   - If you pulled a non-valid IP address, verify the validity of the Network port and activity on the back of the computer.
10. Verify the location (if you didnt pre-add the computer at pt 8) and move to the appropriate branch/folder.

Now all of this assuming you are doing this with a **Physical Computer**.

If you are doing with a **Virtual Computer** from VMWare, then you will have to verify these points of problems:

1. VMachines equipment settings, make sure they are similar/same as other valid VBoxes.
2. Make sure you havent outspent your licensed number of CPU's or Instances

I cant remember if AD is licensed anymore by client licenses or not, or if they just bulked it in with the Server License.  They have changed the CAL licensing options so much over the year its hard for implementors to keep track, only the sales people ;)